# Import question

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, Im new in ROS and Im having a problem importing a .py file from my scripts folder to another .py in the nodes folder of the package.

I know how to import anything in the src folder, but I cant find information about how to do what I wanna do.

Maybe this is a silly question, but I'll apreciate any help. Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206967/import-question/) by [Leontes](https://answers.ros.org/users/22116/leontes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you'll have to add the scripts folder in the PYTHON_PATH. But it's probably better to change the layout of your project (move the script inside src?)

---

Originally posted by [clynamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8871/clynamen/) with karma: 61 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0